# What select statement can I use to determine 1) the roles that a user belongs to and 2) the tables that a user has access to using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Using psql, `\dg` and `\du` tells me the roles that each user (role) belongs to. I want to determine this programmatically for a single user but cannot find which system tables are used to generate the results returned for `\dg`.
Will I need special privileges to execute this query?

As a related question, I want to determine what tables a role can update.
I've read the documentation on `CREATE ROLE` and `GRANT` and surrounding documentation which tell me how to set up roles and privileges, but not how to test for role membership or table access privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are built-in system information functions for both. See [`pg_has_role`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html), etc.

You can also query [the `information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) to get role membership data, in particular [`information_schema.applicable_roles`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-applicable-roles.html), [`information_schema.enabled_roles`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-enabled-roles.html) and [`information_schema.administrable_role_authorizations`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-administrable-role-authorizations.html).

Finally, for any psql `\d` command you can find out what exactly `psql` is doing to get the information by running `psql` with the `-E` option to print the sql it runs. I don't recommend using `psql`'s sql when there's a builtin function or an `information_schema` view for the same information though. `psql`'s approach may be faster but it's also more PostgreSQL-version-specific and may not work with PostgreSQL versions other than the one you're running. In the case of `\du` and `\dg` `psql` will be querying `pg_catalog.pg_roles` as part of a join against other tables. It's much simpler and more portable to use the `information_schema`  views instead.

This really should be [the documentation entries on role membership](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-membership.html); I'll post a patch that adds appropriate cross-references.